# Amazon OpsWorks not mounting EBS volumes after instance reboot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I've configured an OpsWorks stack and my layer is set up so that a 50 GB volume will be attached to each instance I launch.

A new EBS volume gets correctly created, attached and mounted to newly launched instances. Here's what I see immediately after the first boot:

```
[root@biscotti ec2-user]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  1.9G  5.9G  25% /
tmpfs           298M     0  298M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdi        50G   33M   50G   1% /srv/www          <---------
[root@biscotti ec2-user]# mount
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
/dev/xvdi on /srv/www type xfs (rw,noatime)             <---------
```

However, if I reboot the instance, the volume will not be automatically re-mounted:

```
[root@biscotti ec2-user]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  1.9G  5.9G  25% /
tmpfs           298M     0  298M   0% /dev/shm
[root@biscotti ec2-user]# mount
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
```

If I type

```
sudo mount -a
```

everything will get back to normal:

```
[root@biscotti ec2-user]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  1.9G  5.9G  25% /
tmpfs           298M     0  298M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdi        50G   33M   50G   1% /srv/www
[root@biscotti ec2-user]# mount
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
/dev/xvdi on /srv/www type xfs (rw,noatime)
```

How do I get OpsWorks to re-mount the EBS volume automatically for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you adding the volume to the /etc/fstab? If mount -a works then I'm guessing yes, but then it should be mounted during a reboot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I raised the issue with the AWS support and it turned out to be an issue with OpsWorks. One crucial thing for the bug to be reproducible is that I was rebooting the instance by typing `sudo reboot` on the command line. If I stop and restart the instance through the API or the AWS console instead, the volume gets correctly mounted. Quoting literally the AWS support:

> OpsWorks is a very procedural service. It likes to manage its own resources without manual intervention if at all possible. Perhaps the manual OS reboot is overriding some part of the OpsWorks process.

I was told that the OpsWorksdev team is addressing the issue. The problem can also be fixed by adding the `auto` option to the EBS device in the `/etc/fstab` file with a custom Chef recipe.

I hope this will help those who bump into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround which we had to use was to customize the default attributes of the opsworks_initial_setup cookbook ([original](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/opsworks_initial_setup/attributes/default.rb)).

With the following customize.rb:

```
default[:opsworks_initial_setup][:bind_mounts][:mounts] = {}
```

But of course the Amazon recommendation is to use a [symlink](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinglayers-basics-edit.html#d0e11369).